# regexp_similar '^.$' issues in teradata

Tags: regex, teradata

For data scrubbing I have lot of hard coded values in my program. I am trying to put those values into a table. One of the conditions for this scrubbing is to find the length of the character and code `(character_length(name) = 1)`.

But when I try to emulate the this by using `^.$`, it is not catching values like `¿`, `¥`, `Ã`

please let me know if I am doing something wrong .

When I run below code  and I see this 3 values ¿, ¥, Ã

```
select name from email_table
where character_length(name) = 1
and name not in
    (select name from email_table
    where regexp_similar(translate(name USING LATIN_TO_UNICODE WITH ERROR),'^.$', 'i') = 1)
```

Comment: Sounds very much like Teradata's regular expressions match byte sequences rather than character/codepoint strings.

Comment: This works fine for me. Why do you use TRANSLATE when your source column is LATIN?

Comment: Yes. source column is in Latin and if do not use translate I get  message SELECT Failed.  [6706] The string contains an untranslatable character.

Comment: @dnoeth I have tested  as following by creating table and manually inserting values  and tested as follows select name from unicode_table
where regexp_similar(unicode_table,'^.$', 'i')=1 and it still not selects above mentioned values

Comment: What is your Teradata release? You probably loaded unicode data using a latin or ascii session character set. What is returned for `CHAR2HEXINT(name)`?

Comment: char2hexint(name) for those values are 00A5, 00BF,                                                                                   00C3

Comment: What is the result for the original column where you found those characters? You wrote it's LATIN, but `00A5` is UNICODE.

Comment: but now everything is Unicode as I have manually entered this values in Unicode column

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is due to version. 
We have TD14 and TD 15 on different servers and I did following query
select case when regexp_similar('¥','^.$', 'i')=1
         then 'Y'
         else 'N'
         end as output;
In case of TD 14,  I get output as 'N' and in case of TD 15 answer is 'Y'.